# JMeter Performance testing is failing at OAuth2 authorization - Token expired

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, azure-active-directory

We are doing load testing on a portal which uses Azure AAD authentication using JMeter and it is currently failing with this issue:

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70008: The provided authorization code or refresh token has expired due to inactivity. Send a new interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: e4af3a0a-84cc-4f7e-854f-09XXXXXX9a00\r\nCorrelation ID: 54b8a5fd-b1ea-4c1f-bfe0-505XXXXXX944\r\nTimestamp: 2022-06-21 12:14:23Z","error_codes":[70008],"timestamp":"2022-06-21 12:14:23Z","trace_id":"e4af3a0a-84cc-4f7e-854f-0975ea5a9a00","correlation_id":"54b8a5fd-b1ea-4c1f-bfe0-5058478be944","error_uri":"https://login.windows.net/error?code=70008"}

Could you please help us troubleshoot the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you recorded the test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) - at some point you won't be able to replay the test as OAuth tokens have [limited life time](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/).

You will need to go through [full authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oauth2) until you get the new token, extract it from the response using suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace recorded token value with the variable holding the token.

The process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations/) and there is a lot of information on the topic in the Internet.